# Is it possible to restart streaming to YouTube live after it was automatically closed?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am building a monitoring system which streams video to YouTube live during the day, but it is shut down during the night. YouTube live automatically closes the stream when it stops receiving data.

I could start another stream using the API, but I would like to keep the same YouTube URL for the public. Is this possible?

The system is solar powered raspberry pi monitoring a birds colony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your encoder momentarily stops sending data to YouTube's RTMP ingestion address, it will enter a "technical difficulties" state.  After some constant amount of time (which is not listed in the API), YouTube will forcefully end your live event.

If you know the rough timeframe when your Raspberry Pi device will go down, why not stream a "We will be back tomorrow" message from a computer or other source with stable power and internet connection, so YouTube will not end your event.

Comment: It would be doable, but there are few glitches in this approach. The raspberry system is powered by a solar panel and it may be turned off because of a low battery at random time. There could be another system pinging the raspberry and detecting its power-down state, and then starting or stopping the "We will be back soon" stream. If there is no youtube-API-way of solving these power-downs, then that would be the good solution. Thanks a lot.